# Are you able to add shared inboxes to your Outlook for Mac?

Tags: outlook, office365

I have a user that uses a Mac in the IOS environment while the rest of the users use Microsoft. She has access to multiple shared inboxes, but her Outlook (for Mac) only displays her personal account. When I tried to add the rest of the accounts, it is asking me for a password, but they are shared accounts that do not have passwords.

Can you please advice?

Thank you, 
Andrea Aznar

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps to add a Shared Mailbox in a Mac Machine. It should not prompt you for credentials if you have permissions to access the mailbox. 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/open-a-shared-folder-or-mailbox-in-outlook-for-mac-6ecc39c5-5577-4a1d-b18c-bbdc92972cb2

I think you are getting the credential prompt because you are trying to add another Exchange account by using additional mailboxes credentials. This method is not recognized as adding a shared mailbox, because you are adding the additional account by using its own credentials.